# How to send an image to another viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I have a program where I am combining two images into a single image on an UIImageView on my main ViewController.  I would like to set that combined image to UIImageView on another viewController in order to preview it full size.  I can do all of this, I just can't figure out how to send this image to the other viewcontroller's UIImageView.

How can a set an image to a UIImageView that is on a different viewController?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use the delegate pattern, add a method such as:

```
-(void)viewController: (UIViewController*)vc didReturnImage: (UIImage*)image;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should make an image object on that view controller where you have to show the image and then set image to that image object like:-
In forthViewController do

```
UIImage *img;

@property(nonatomic,retain)UIImage *img;
```

Make sure you make property and synthesize img.

In the view Controller where you have that image:-

```
ForthViewController *forthView=[[[ForthViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ForthViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
forthView.img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:forthView animated:YES];
```

In you view controller where you have to show image do:-

```
UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
[imgView setImage:self.img];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

I hope this code will work for you basically you can get the image of prevoius view controller now you can do want you want to as (combine ..)
Happy Coding:)

Comment: This is the routine that worked for me.  I certainly appreciate everybody's response and so quickly.  @jlehr:  your answer looks very simple, but I don't understand how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Who owns the second view controller? Somewhere in your code, you should be able to reference that second view controller. Then, in the second view controller, just create a method called `setImage:(UIImage *)image` that takes a UIImage and assigns it as the image view's image.

Answer (score 0):

```
SecondViewImage *VC = [[SecondViewImage alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewImage" bundle:nil] ;

[VC loadView];

VC.theImage.image = chosenImage;
VC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];

Note: loadView is required.